# Add 1 to variable Starting from random number AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, variables, flash-cc

I am in the process of creating an interactive map which gives users the option of clicking on a random site, viewing the content and then either going back to the overview, or continuing on to the next site.

I am having trouble adding 1 to the site number, when the users click "next site". Instead of continuing on to the next site, it goes on from a random number.

My code for the view site button

```
vmsite1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mouseDownHandlervmsite1); 
function mouseDownHandlervmsite1(event:MouseEvent):void 
  { 
   gotoAndStop(33); // WHERE THE DYNAMIC CONTENT LOADS

    var siteNumber = 1;

  }
```

My code for the next button:

```
 next_site1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mouseDownHandlernext_site1); 
   function mouseDownHandlernext_site1(event:MouseEvent):void 
        { 
            siteNumber = siteNumber;
            if (siteNumber <= 29) {
            siteNumber ++;
            }
            else {
                siteNumber = siteNumber;
            }
            // UNLOAD THE PREVIOUS SLIDE SHOW
            myLoader.unload();
            SiteNumberText1.text = siteNumber.toString();
            site1scroll.scrollTarget = field;   
            loadData();
            // LOAD THE SLIDE SHOW
            var urlforswfcomp2:URLRequest = new URLRequest(URLSWF + siteNumber + imgext);  
            myLoader.load(urlforswfcomp2); 

        }
```

I have had a look through the AS3 guide on the Adobe website, but I can't find an issue similar to mine.

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7fcf.html

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/actionscript/learning/as3-fundamentals/operators.html

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: When you declare a variable inside of a function, like `var siteNumber = 1;` that variable only exists inside the function. If you want other functions to be able to use it's value, you need to declare the variable outside of the function. Also statements like `siteNumber = siteNumber` have no real use, you're assigning the same variable to itself.

Comment: @SunilD. can you suggest a fix for the error?
If i dont have the siteNumber=siteNumber in the else statement, the increment keeps increasing.

Comment: Well, I would move the declaration of `siteNumber` so that it is outside of the function `mouseDownHandlervmsite1`. But, admittedly, I'm a bit confused as to what is going on based on your last statement. Do you have any other related code that you can show?

Comment: That worked. I have tried putting the siteNumber variable everywhere, but always got errors. It seems to work now though. Thank you! @SunilD.

Answer (score 0):

I moved my siteNumber variable definition outside the button code, and it worked. This is my new view more button code.

```
var siteNumber:int = 0;

vmsite1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mouseDownHandlervmsite1); 
function mouseDownHandlervmsite1(event:MouseEvent):void 
  { 
   gotoAndStop(33);
   siteNumber = 1
}
```